# Repeat table header on every page using supertabular

Tags: tables, supertabular

This question is related to this one: [How to repeat top rows (column headings) on every page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11380/how-to-repeat-top-rows-column-headings-on-every-page)

But I want to repeat the header row of a table using supertabular and not long table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the manual of **supertabular**, declare

```
\tablehead{<the code you want for the common headings>}
\tablefirsthead{<the code for the first heading>}
\tabletail{<the code for the common bottoms>}
\tablelasttail{<the code for the last table bottom>}
```

just *before* starting the `supertabular`.

Pay attention: the `supertabular` environment and those declarations are to be enclosed in a group (the `center` environment, for instance). Otherwise you'll get the same heads and tails in all `supertabular` tables until you change the value of them.

Answer (score 4):

In the [documentation](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/supertabular) you can find:

> The command `\tablefirsthead` takes one argument, it defines the
>   contents of the first occurence of the tabular head. The use of this
>   command is optional. Don’t forget to close the head by a `\\`.
>
> The command `\tablehead` takes one argument, it defines the contents of all
>   subsequent ocurrences of the tabular head. Don’t forget to close the
>   head by a `\\`

An example is presented is the documentation on page 3f.