# Continue header of a long table in next page

Tags: tables, longtable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to repeat top rows (column headings) on every page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11380/how-to-repeat-top-rows-column-headings-on-every-page)

I have a long table that spans multiple pages. I would like the header of the table to repeat at the top of every new page that is spanned by the table.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Comment: @doncherry: Thanks for that. I'll keep that in mind next time I post anything. BTW, I upvoted your answer as a token of thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I got that.

`longtable` along with command `\endhead` solves the problem.