# How to continue table on multiple pages?

Tags: tables

I am writing one table which is very long may occupy 2-3 pages. I need to split this table on multiple pages but with same table header at the beginning of table. I am using long-table which allow table to continue on multiple pages. But How can i keep same header on multiple pages.

Regards

Comment: See this question: [How to repeat top rows (column headings) on every page](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11380) (possible duplicate).

Comment: It would be nice to know if the answers to the question I linked to helped you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A short answer would be [long table](http://cs.brown.edu/system/software/latex/doc/longtable.pdf).

Longer answer would require further input from you - Like MWE

Comment: long table only split table but does not keep same table header on multiple pages.

Comment: It does, see Section 3 on page 4.

Comment: I used \endfirsthead and \endhead but i found table caption overlaps with table. How can i overcome such pblm.

Comment: user15662: I think it would be better to start a new question and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).