# Name, address, email Template (sort of empty table) for the attendees of a seminar?

Tags: tables, templates

I want a three column "Name", "Address", "email" template with appropriate spacing. I know how to do this in MS word. But I am just curious how to do it in Latex? I might need space in the heading for including the details of the seminar.

EDIT: My poor writing skills has made it impossible for people to answer on this.
I tried to make a minimal working example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}      
\begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
Name & Affliation & Email \\
\hline
\endhead 
 &  &  \\
\hline
 &  &  \\
\hline
&  &  \\
\hline
&  &  \\
\hline
&  &  \\
\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Now I want to adjust the size of rows and columns coming out of this table. I hope that clears it.

Comment: Just a simple `tabular` should be sufficient, no?  You might want to use the `tabularx` package for adjusting the width of one or more of the columns.

Comment: The thing is I don't know how many rows will be needed. I just know the size of each cell. Then I want as many as rows as possible in a given page.

Comment: The `longtable` package allows tables to split across pages with repeating headers and footers.

Comment: I checked it. But seems like it needs the number of rows in advance and the rows as such in advance. Are you suggesting to hard code each row with empty entries and have as many row as I want?

Comment: See [How to repeat top rows (column headings) on every page](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11380) for some examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be always be done with direct typing into tex file or typing addresses in to a `csv` file.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{ltablex,booktabs}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[linkbordercolor={0 0 0},colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in,heightrounded,showframe]{geometry}     %% remove showframe
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{participants.csv}
Name,address,email
Ms. Veena Saraf,"Some address goes here, Some street, Some place", vena\_saf03@yahoo.com
Ms. Roopa Chanachetty,"Some address goes here, Some street, Some place", ropa\_vc3@yahoo.co.in
Mr. Richard Rathnam,"Some address goes here, Some street, Some place", richard\_ratam@rediffmail.com
\end{filecontents*}
\newcounter{rowno}
\setcounter{rowno}{0}
\usepackage{datatool}
\DTLloaddb{names}{participants.csv}
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.5}
%==================================================================
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\Large\bfseries List of participants
\end{center}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\stepcounter{rowno}\therowno.}c
    >{\setlength{\hsize}{8\hsize}\raggedright\arraybackslash}X   %% adjust 8\hsize suitably
    >{\setlength{\hsize}{13\hsize}\raggedright\arraybackslash}X  %% adjust 13\hsize suitably 
    >{\setlength{\hsize}{12\hsize}\raggedright\arraybackslash}X} %% adjust 12\hsize suitably
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textnumero} &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{Name} &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{Address} &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{e-mail}\\ \toprule
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textnumero} &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{Name} &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{Address} &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{e-mail}\\ \toprule
\endhead

\DTLforeach{names}{
\name=Name, \place=address, \email=email}{%
\DTLiffirstrow{}{\\}
  & \name & \place & \url{\email}
}
\end{tabularx}%
%===============================================================
\end{document}
```

[image]

Type the particulars in the `participants.csv` file using excel or similar application. Adjust the `\hsize`s and you are ready to go.

**Edit**
As per the comment, an empty table is needed. However, since *enough space* is only relative, dimensions may need to be adjusted. Take multiple copies of the page and use.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,array,textcomp}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2cm,heightrounded]{geometry}
%
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\null
\vspace{1.3\baselineskip}
\begin{center}
    \Large\bfseries Some details\\[-.5\baselineskip]
    \rule{\textwidth}{2pt}
\end{center}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|XX|XX|XX|}\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textnumero} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Name} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Address} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{email}\\\hline
 & & & & & & \\[3\baselineskip]\hline
 & & & & & & \\[3\baselineskip]\hline
 & & & & & & \\[3\baselineskip]\hline
 & & & & & & \\[3\baselineskip]\hline
 & & & & & & \\[3\baselineskip]\hline
 & & & & & & \\[3\baselineskip]\hline
 & & & & & & \\[3\baselineskip]\hline
 & & & & & & \\[3\baselineskip]\hline
 & & & & & & \\[3\baselineskip]\hline
 & & & & & & \\[3\baselineskip]\hline
 & & & & & & \\[3\baselineskip]\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the effort. In my case, the list of attendees is not yet known. We will distribute this form in the seminar, and everyone is supposed to fill it with their name, affiliation and email.

Comment: @dineshdileep You want an empty table?

Comment: yes, But enough space so that a person can fill his name (first column), address (second column) and email (third column).

Comment: @dineshdileep What is *enough space*? It is always relative. and names (etc) come with variety of lengths!:-)

Comment: I would print the page displayed above without the prefilled names and make a few copies of it.

Comment: @dineshdileep see the edit.

Comment: @HarishKumar thanks a lot!, that helped. But How do I continue to a new page.

Comment: I just read the last sentence now, never mind my comment. Thanks a lot.