# Repeating top rows on every page except for one page?

Tags: tables, longtable

Is there a way to repeat every row on each page except for one page in a table? I checked this post
[How to repeat top rows (column headings) on every page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11380/219675) and this answer
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/11381/219675

However, this only partially answers my question since I do not want to repeat the top rows on the last page.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a compilable short TeX code you have so far! Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...