# Different header rows in different pages of a long table

Tags: tables, tabularray

I came across [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/622599/repeating-top-rows-on-every-page-except-for-one-page) which wants no header rows on the last page. While trying to find a way for that I was wondering if it's possible to have different header rows on different pages automatically. An MWE is given with the `tabularray` package but it's not necessary to use this package for a solution. So, is it possible to have different header rows on different pages?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtblr}[
 caption = {A Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Table},
 entry = {Short Caption},
 label = {tblr:test},
]{
 colspec = {XXX}, width = 0.85\linewidth,
 rowhead = 2, rowfoot = 1,
 row{odd} = {gray9}, row{even} = {brown9},
 row{1-2} = {purple7}, row{Z} = {blue7},
}

\hline
 Head & Head & Head \\
\hline
 Head & Head & Head \\
\hline
 Alpha & Beta & Gamma \\
\hline
 Epsilon & Zeta & Eta \\
\hline
 Iota & Kappa & Lambda \\
\hline
 Nu & Xi & Omicron \\
\hline
 Rho & Sigma & Tau \\
\hline
 Phi & Chi & Psi \\
\hline
 Alpha & Beta & Gamma \\
\hline
 Epsilon & Zeta & Eta \\
\hline
 Iota & Kappa & Lambda \\
\hline
 Nu & Xi & Omicron \\
\hline
 Rho & Sigma & Tau \\
\hline
 Phi & Chi & Psi \\
\hline
 Alpha & Beta & Gamma \\
\hline
 Epsilon & Zeta & Eta \\
\hline
 Iota & Kappa & Lambda \\
\hline
 Nu & Xi & Omicron \\
\hline
 Rho & Sigma & Tau \\
\hline
 Phi & Chi & Psi \\
\hline
 Alpha & Beta & Gamma \\
\hline
 Epsilon & Zeta & Eta \\
\hline
 Iota & Kappa & Lambda \\
\hline
 Nu & Xi & Omicron \\
\hline
 Rho & Sigma & Tau \\
\hline
 Phi & Chi & Psi \\
\hline
 Alpha & Beta & Gamma \\
\hline
 Epsilon & Zeta & Eta \\
\hline
 Iota & Kappa & Lambda \\
\hline
 Nu & Xi & Omicron \\
\hline
 Rho & Sigma & Tau \\
\hline
 Phi & Chi & Psi \\
\hline
 Alpha & Beta & Gamma \\
\hline
 Epsilon & Zeta & Eta \\
\hline
 Iota & Kappa & Lambda \\
\hline
 Nu & Xi & Omicron \\
\hline
 Rho & Sigma & Tau \\
\hline
 Phi & Chi & Psi \\
\hline
 Alpha & Beta & Gamma \\
\hline
 Epsilon & Zeta & Eta \\
\hline
 Iota & Kappa & Lambda \\
\hline
 Nu & Xi & Omicron \\
\hline
 Rho & Sigma & Tau \\
\hline
 Phi & Chi & Psi \\
\hline
 Alpha & Beta & Gamma \\
\hline
 Epsilon & Zeta & Eta \\
\hline
 Iota & Kappa & Lambda \\
\hline
 Nu & Xi & Omicron \\
\hline
 Rho & Sigma & Tau \\
\hline
 Phi & Chi & Psi \\
\hline
 Alpha & Beta & Gamma \\
\hline
 Epsilon & Zeta & Eta \\
\hline
 Iota & Kappa & Lambda \\
\hline
 Nu & Xi & Omicron \\
\hline
 Rho & Sigma & Tau \\
\hline
 Phi & Chi & Psi \\
\hline
 Alpha & Beta & Gamma \\
\hline
 Epsilon & Zeta & Eta \\
\hline
 Iota & Kappa & Lambda \\
\hline
 Nu & Xi & Omicron \\
\hline
 Rho & Sigma & Tau \\
\hline
 Phi & Chi & Psi \\
\hline
 Alpha & Beta & Gamma \\
\hline
 Epsilon & Zeta & Eta \\
\hline
 Iota & Kappa & Lambda \\
\hline
 Nu & Xi & Omicron \\
\hline
 Rho & Sigma & Tau \\
\hline
 Phi & Chi & Psi \\
\hline
 Alpha & Beta & Gamma \\
\hline
 Epsilon & Zeta & Eta \\
\hline
 Iota & Kappa & Lambda \\
\hline
 Nu & Xi & Omicron \\
\hline
 Rho & Sigma & Tau \\
\hline
 Phi & Chi & Psi \\
\hline
 Alpha & Beta & Gamma \\
\hline
 Epsilon & Zeta & Eta \\
\hline
 Iota & Kappa & Lambda \\
\hline
 Nu & Xi & Omicron \\
\hline
 Rho & Sigma & Tau \\
\hline
 Phi & Chi & Psi \\
\hline
 Alpha & Beta & Gamma \\
\hline
 Epsilon & Zeta & Eta \\
\hline
 Iota & Kappa & Lambda \\
\hline
 Nu & Xi & Omicron \\
\hline
 Rho & Sigma & Tau \\
\hline
 Phi & Chi & Psi \\
\hline
 Alpha & Beta & Gamma \\
\hline
 Epsilon & Zeta & Eta \\
\hline
 Iota & Kappa & Lambda \\
\hline
 Nu & Xi & Omicron \\
\hline
 Rho & Sigma & Tau \\
\hline
 Phi & Chi & Psi \\
\hline
 Alpha & Beta & Gamma \\
\hline
 Epsilon & Zeta & Eta \\
\hline
 Iota & Kappa & Lambda \\
\hline
 Nu & Xi & Omicron \\
\hline
 Rho & Sigma & Tau \\
\hline
 Phi & Chi & Psi \\
\hline
 Alpha & Beta & Gamma \\
\hline
 Epsilon & Zeta & Eta \\
\hline
 Iota & Kappa & Lambda \\
\hline
 Nu & Xi & Omicron \\
\hline
 Rho & Sigma & Tau \\
\hline
 Phi & Chi & Psi \\
\hline
 Alpha & Beta & Gamma \\
\hline
 Epsilon & Zeta & Eta \\
\hline
 Iota & Kappa & Lambda \\
\hline
 Nu & Xi & Omicron \\
\hline
 Rho & Sigma & Tau \\
\hline
 Phi & Chi & Psi \\
\hline
 Foot & Foot & Foot \\
\hline
\end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

Comment: note you have tagged this longtable but longtable and tabulararry do not share any code so any solution for one will not apply to the other, you may want to tag both packages and make your title clearer that you refer to a generic "long table" not specifically `longtable`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks, edited the title. Please add the appropriate tag or remove the inappropriate one. Solution using any package is acceptable and I am not sure which tag to add in that case (I thought longtable tag wasn't related to any package, so I added that).

Comment: if you hover over the longtable tag below your question you will see it references the package there is this for longtable https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/263597/change-endhead-in-the-middle-of-a-longtable/263602#263602

Comment: The  row head and foot are saved in boxes at the beginning of the `tblr` construction, and so they cannot be changed mid-table. You could try to put this information in the table head instead, (as a mini `tblr` in the `capcont` template), but it would probably be difficult to align it with the main table.

Comment: @PietervanOostrum If possible, please write an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The row head and foot are saved in boxes at the beginning of the tblr construction, and so they cannot be changed mid-table. You could try to put this information in the table head instead, and then you can differentiate between first, middle and last head. These are also put in boxes, so you can only differentiate between the first end last one, and all the intermediate ones (the latter ones will be all the same).

Here is an example of how this could be done. I have used the `capcont` template, which applies to all headers after the first one. If you want to differentiate between the middle and the last headers, you should use the `middlehead` and `lasthead` templates instead.

It could use some improvement in the spacing. If you use different colspecs the header might not align with the rest of the table.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\newcommand\RowHead{Head-2}
\DefTblrTemplate {conthead-text}{rowheads}{%
  (Continued)\par
  \begin{tblr}{colspec = {XXX}, width = 0.85\textwidth,
      row{odd} = {gray9}, row{even} = {brown9},
      row{1-2} = {purple7}, row{Z} = {blue7},
    }
    \hline
    \RowHead & \RowHead & \RowHead \\
    \hline
    \RowHead & \RowHead & \RowHead
  \end{tblr}
  }

\DefTblrTemplate{capcont}{rowheads}{%
  \par\centering
  \UseTblrTemplate {caption-tag}{default}%
  \UseTblrTemplate {caption-sep}{default}%
  \UseTblrTemplate {caption-text}{default}%
  \UseTblrTemplate {conthead-text}{rowheads}%
}
\NewTblrTheme{rowheads}{%
    \SetTblrTemplate{capcont}{rowheads}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtblr}[
 theme=rowheads,
 headsep=0pt,
 caption = {A Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Table},
 entry = {Short Caption},
 label = {tblr:test},
]{
 colspec = {XXX}, width = 0.85\textwidth,
 rowhead = 0, rowfoot = 1,
 row{odd} = {gray9}, row{even} = {brown9},
 row{1-2} = {purple7}, row{Z} = {blue7},
}

\hline
 Head & Head & Head \\
\hline
 Head & Head & Head \\
\hline
 Alpha & Beta & Gamma \\
\hline
 Epsilon & Zeta & Eta \\
\hline
 Iota & Kappa & Lambda \\
\hline
 Nu & Xi & Omicron \\
\hline
 Rho & Sigma & Tau \\
\hline
 Phi & Chi & Psi \\
\hline
 Alpha & Beta & Gamma \\
\hline
 Epsilon & Zeta & Eta \\
\hline
 Iota & Kappa & Lambda \\
\hline
 Nu & Xi & Omicron \\
\hline
 Rho & Sigma & Tau \\
\hline
 Phi & Chi & Psi \\
\hline
 Alpha & Beta & Gamma \\
\hline
 Epsilon & Zeta & Eta \\
\hline
 Iota & Kappa & Lambda \\
\hline
 Nu & Xi & Omicron \\
\hline
 Rho & Sigma & Tau \\
\hline
 Phi & Chi & Psi \\
\hline
 Alpha & Beta & Gamma \\
\hline
 Epsilon & Zeta & Eta \\
\hline
 Iota & Kappa & Lambda \\
\hline
 Nu & Xi & Omicron \\
\hline
 Rho & Sigma & Tau \\
\hline
 Phi & Chi & Psi \\
\hline
 Alpha & Beta & Gamma \\
\hline
 Epsilon & Zeta & Eta \\
\hline
 Iota & Kappa & Lambda \\
\hline
 Nu & Xi & Omicron \\
\hline
 Rho & Sigma & Tau \\
\hline
 Phi & Chi & Psi \\
\hline
 Alpha & Beta & Gamma \\
\hline
 Epsilon & Zeta & Eta \\
\hline
 Iota & Kappa & Lambda \\
\hline
 Nu & Xi & Omicron \\
\hline
 Rho & Sigma & Tau \\
\hline
 Phi & Chi & Psi \\
\hline
 Alpha & Beta & Gamma \\
\hline
 Epsilon & Zeta & Eta \\
\hline
 Iota & Kappa & Lambda \\
\hline
 Nu & Xi & Omicron \\
\hline
 Rho & Sigma & Tau \\
\hline
 Phi & Chi & Psi \\
\hline
 Alpha & Beta & Gamma \\
\hline
 Epsilon & Zeta & Eta \\
\hline
 Iota & Kappa & Lambda \\
\hline
 Nu & Xi & Omicron \\
\hline
 Rho & Sigma & Tau \\
\hline
 Phi & Chi & Psi \\
\hline
 Alpha & Beta & Gamma \\
\hline
 Epsilon & Zeta & Eta \\
\hline
 Iota & Kappa & Lambda \\
\hline
 Nu & Xi & Omicron \\
\hline
 Rho & Sigma & Tau \\
\hline
 Phi & Chi & Psi \\
\hline
 Alpha & Beta & Gamma \\
\hline
 Epsilon & Zeta & Eta \\
\hline
 Iota & Kappa & Lambda \\
\hline
 Nu & Xi & Omicron \\
\hline
 Rho & Sigma & Tau \\
\hline
 Phi & Chi & Psi \\
\hline
 Alpha & Beta & Gamma \\
\hline
 Epsilon & Zeta & Eta \\
\hline
 Iota & Kappa & Lambda \\
\hline
 Nu & Xi & Omicron \\
\hline
 Rho & Sigma & Tau \\
\hline
 Phi & Chi & Psi \\
\hline
 Alpha & Beta & Gamma \\
\hline
 Epsilon & Zeta & Eta \\
\hline
 Iota & Kappa & Lambda \\
\hline
 Nu & Xi & Omicron \\
\hline
 Rho & Sigma & Tau \\
\hline
 Phi & Chi & Psi \\
\hline
 Alpha & Beta & Gamma \\
\hline
 Epsilon & Zeta & Eta \\
\hline
 Iota & Kappa & Lambda \\
\hline
 Nu & Xi & Omicron \\
\hline
 Rho & Sigma & Tau \\
\hline
 Phi & Chi & Psi \\
\hline
 Alpha & Beta & Gamma \\
\hline
 Epsilon & Zeta & Eta \\
\hline
 Iota & Kappa & Lambda \\
\hline
 Nu & Xi & Omicron \\
\hline
 Rho & Sigma & Tau \\
\hline
 Phi & Chi & Psi \\
\hline
 Alpha & Beta & Gamma \\
\hline
 Epsilon & Zeta & Eta \\
\hline
 Iota & Kappa & Lambda \\
\hline
 Nu & Xi & Omicron \\
\hline
 Rho & Sigma & Tau \\
\hline
 Phi & Chi & Psi \\
\hline
 Alpha & Beta & Gamma \\
\hline
 Epsilon & Zeta & Eta \\
\hline
 Iota & Kappa & Lambda \\
\hline
 Nu & Xi & Omicron \\
\hline
 Rho & Sigma & Tau \\
\hline
 Phi & Chi & Psi \\
\hline
 Alpha & Beta & Gamma \\
\hline
 Epsilon & Zeta & Eta \\
\hline
 Iota & Kappa & Lambda \\
\hline
 Nu & Xi & Omicron \\
\hline
 Rho & Sigma & Tau \\
\hline
 Phi & Chi & Psi \\
\hline
 Alpha & Beta & Gamma \\
\hline
 Epsilon & Zeta & Eta \\
\hline
 Iota & Kappa & Lambda \\
\hline
 Nu & Xi & Omicron \\
\hline
 Rho & Sigma & Tau \\
\hline
 Phi & Chi & Psi \\
\hline
 Foot & Foot & Foot \\
\hline
\end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: How can one remove the small white gap between the purple row 2 with the text Head-2 and the continued table?

Comment: Add a `\vspace{-2pt}` after `\end{tblr}`.

Comment: I have done this. I was hoping for a cleaner way by not introducing the whitespace in the first place.

Comment: I found out what caused it and I edited the solution: (1)remove the `\hline` before `\end{tabular}` ; (2) remove the `\par` at the end of the template. I also replaced `\linewidth` by `\textwidth`.

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not work for me. I will go with `\vspace{-6pt}` which is the value from footsep.