# When I type more text, the long table collapses

Tags: tables

When I type more than 3 lines of text in the table, the table collapses, could anyone help?

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{setspace}% for\doublespacing
\usepackage{indentfirst}% for indent the first line
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{textalpha}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % <-- new
\usepackage{xltabular} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{caption}



\begin{document}


 \newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X} % suspend full justification
% special new column type for header row:
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}%
    p{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth\relax}}


\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{ | l | L | c | } % <-- new
  
 %% headers and footers
\caption{DUSP genes in normal and pathological brain function\label{long4}}\\
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{ | C | }{DUSP genes in normal and pathological brain function}\\
\hline
Isoforms & Function in Normal Brain & Function in Pathological Brain  \\
\hline
\endfirsthead
 
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Continuation of Table \ref{long4}}\\
\hline
Isoforms & Function in Normal Brain& Function in Pathological Brain  \\
\hline
\endhead
 
\hline
\endfoot
 
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{| c |}{End of Table}\\
\hline
\hline
\endlastfoot

SSH1  &  long text long text long text long text long text long text  & long textlong text long text long text  \\
SSH2     & long text long text long text long text   &  long text long text long text long text \\    
SSH1  &  long text long text long text long text long text long text  & long textlong text long text long text long textlong text long text long text  \\

             \end{xltabular}
 % This is footnote
\begin{minipage}{10cm}
\small AD: Alzheimer’s disease; HD: Huntingdon’s disease; CMT4: Charcot-Marie-Tooth Neuropathy Type 4. 
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

This is ideal form.

[image]

The code gives collapsed table:

[image]

Comment: A column type `c` doesn't allow line breaks.  Do you really want that third column center aligned?

Comment: I just want the table center aligned, the column does not matter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to allow automatic line breaking in both columns 2 and 3. I therefore suggest you replace

```
\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{ | l | L | c | }
```

with

```
\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{ | l | L | L | }
```

If, for some reason, you want the contents of the cells in column 3 to be centered instead of left-aligned, I suggest you execute

```
\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\Centering}X}
```

in the preamble and use

```
\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{ | l | L | Z | }
```

instead of `\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{ | l | L | L | }`

---

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{setspace}% for\doublespacing
\usepackage{indentfirst}% for indent the first line
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xltabular} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{caption}

\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X} % suspend full justification
% special new column type for header row:
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}%
    p{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth\relax}}

\begin{document}

\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{ | l | L | L | } % <-- new
  
 %% headers and footers
\caption{DUSP genes in normal and pathological brain function\label{long4}}\\
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{ | C | }{DUSP genes in normal and pathological brain function}\\
\hline
Isoforms & Function in Normal Brain & Function in Pathological Brain  \\
\hline
\endfirsthead
 
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Continuation of Table \ref{long4}}\\
\hline
Isoforms & Function in Normal Brain& Function in Pathological Brain  \\
\hline
\endhead
 
\hline
\endfoot
 
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{| C |}{End of Table}\\
\hline
\endlastfoot

SSH1 & long text long text long text long text long text long text  & long textlong text long text long text \\
SSH2 & long text long text long text long text & long text long text long text long text \\    
SSH1 & long text long text long text long text long text long text  & long textlong text long text long text long textlong text long text long text \\

\end{xltabular}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\small AD: Alzheimer’s disease; HD: Huntingdon’s disease; CMT4: Charcot-Marie-Tooth Neuropathy Type 4. 
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Slightly expanding on [Mico](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/692607/31283)'s answer.
The reason is two columns in your screenshot are not of the same width.
It's possible to achieve this effect with `X`-type columns if you specify explicit proportions.
The format is

```
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\hsize=<factor>\hsize\linewidth=\hsize}X}
\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\hsize=<2-factor>\hsize\linewidth=\hsize}X}
```

Note that factors should add up to a number of columns of type `X`, which is `2` in the example.
It's explained in [documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) section 4.3. In the example below, I choose relative widths of 0.8 and 1.2 (note that, as required, 0.8+1.2=2), which implies that the *usable* width of the second X-type column is 50% larger than that of the first.

I would make annotation a part of the table to avoid unexpected separation on page breaks. I would also stretch the table a bit to add more space to rows.

Here's the final code

```latex
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{setspace}% for\doublespacing
\usepackage{indentfirst}% for indent the first line
\usepackage{textalpha}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % <-- new
\usepackage{xltabular} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{caption}

\newlength\tabwidth
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\RaggedRight\hsize=.8\hsize\linewidth=\hsize}X}
\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\RaggedRight\hsize=1.2\hsize\linewidth=\hsize}X}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth}}


\begin{document}
\begingroup
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}
  \begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{|l|Y|Z|} % <-- new
    %% headers and footers
    \caption{DUSP genes in normal and pathological brain function\label{long4}}\\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{3}{|C|}{DUSP genes in normal and pathological brain function}\\
    \hline
    Isoforms
    & Function in Normal Brain
    & Function in Pathological Brain  \\
    \hline
    \endfirsthead
    \hline
    \multicolumn{3}{|C|}{Continuation of Table \ref{long4}}\\
    \hline
    Isoforms
    & Function in Normal Brain
    & Function in Pathological Brain  \\
    \hline
    \endhead
    \hline
    \endfoot
    \hline
    \multicolumn{3}{|C|}{End of Table}\\
    \hline
    \hline
    \multicolumn{3}{@{}p{\linewidth}@{}}{%
      \rule{0pt}{0.7\normalbaselineskip}%
      \footnotesize
      AD: Alzheimer’s disease; HD: Huntingdon’s disease; CMT4: Charcot-Marie-Tooth Neuropathy Type 4.}
    \endlastfoot
    SSH1
    & long text long text long text long text long text long text
    & long textlong text long text long text  \\
    SSH2
    & long text long text long text long text
    &  long text long text long text long text \\
    SSH1
    & long text long text long text long text long text long text
    & long textlong text long text long text long textlong text long text long text \\
  \end{xltabular}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Are you sure about `\hsize=<factor>\hsize` and `\hsize=<1-factor>\hsize`? Your own practical example uses `0.8` and `1.2`, *not* `0.8` and `0.2`.

Comment: @Mico The numbers were incorrect in the answer. It should be `0.8` and `1.2`. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: +1. Thanks. I've taken the liberty of editing your answer to provide some intuition for what relative widths of 0.8 and 1.2 may mean in practice. (I know that *you* fully well know this; however, newcomers to the world of `tabularx` columns may not, right?) Feel free to revert.

Answer (score 0):

Your table you can also write by use `longtblr` of `tabularray` package. Code is shorter, but compilation time is a bit longer:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

%\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
%\usepackage{indentfirst}% for indent the first line
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath, booktabs}
\SetTblrStyle{contfoot}{font=\footnotesize\itshape}
\SetTblrStyle{note}{font=\small}

\begin{document}
    \begin{longtblr}[
caption = {DUSP genes in normal and pathological brain function},
  label = {long4},
note{}  = {AD: Alzheimer’s disease; HD: Huntingdon’s disease; CMT4: Charcot-Marie-Tooth Neuropathy Type 4.},
                    ]{vlines,
                      colspec      = { l *{2}{X[cmd=\RaggedRight]} },
                      cell{1,Z}{1} = {c=3}{c},
                      row{3-Y}     = {rowsep=3pt},
                      row{2}       = {c},
                      rowhead      = 2
                      }
% column headers
    \toprule
DUSP genes in normal and pathological brain function
    &   &                                               \\
    \midrule
Isoforms 
    & Function in Normal Brain 
        & Function in Pathological Brain                \\
    \midrule
% table body
SSH1    &   long text long text long text long text long text long text  
            &   long textlong text long text long text  \\
SSH2    &   long text long text long text long text 
            & long text long text long text long text   \\
SSH1    &   long text long text long text long text long text long text  
            & long textlong text long text long text long text long text long text long text 
                                                        \\
% table body
SSH1    &   long text long text long text long text long text long text
            &   long textlong text long text long text  \\
SSH2    &   long text long text long text long text
            & long text long text long text long text   \\
SSH1    &   long text long text long text long text long text long text
            & long textlong text long text long text long text long text long text long text
                                                        \\
% table body
SSH1    &   long text long text long text long text long text long text
            &   long textlong text long text long text  \\
SSH2    &   long text long text long text long text
            & long text long text long text long text   \\
SSH1    &   long text long text long text long text long text long text
            & long textlong text long text long text long text long text long text long text
                                                        \\
% table body
SSH1    &   long text long text long text long text long text long text
            &   long textlong text long text long text  \\
SSH2    &   long text long text long text long text
            & long text long text long text long text   \\
SSH1    &   long text long text long text long text long text long text
            & long textlong text long text long text long text long text long text long text
                                                        \\
% table body
SSH1    &   long text long text long text long text long text long text
            &   long textlong text long text long text  \\
SSH2    &   long text long text long text long text
            & long text long text long text long text   \\
SSH1    &   long text long text long text long text long text long text
            & long textlong text long text long text long text long text long text long text
                                                        \\
% table body
SSH1    &   long text long text long text long text long text long text
            &   long textlong text long text long text  \\
SSH2    &   long text long text long text long text
            & long text long text long text long text   \\
SSH1    &   long text long text long text long text long text long text
            & long textlong text long text long text long text long text long text long text
                                                        \\
    \midrule
End of Table
    &   &                       \\
    \bottomrule
   \end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

As you can see, in above MWE in comparison to your MWE are done the following changes:

- for horizontal table lines are used rules defined in the `booktabs` package.
- for text aligned in cells is used `ragged2e` package

In the case, that you like to have different width od the second an third column, you can get this pa scaling `X` specifier, for example:

```
colspec      = { l X[cmd=\RaggedRight]
                   X[1.3, cmd=\RaggedRight]},
```

where the third column is 30% wider than second.

Answer (score 0):

Another answer based on the [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tabularray}

    % Header for pages other than the 1st one
    \DefTblrTemplate{conthead-text}{MyContTxt}{
        \begin{tblr}{
            colspec={lX[l]X[l]},
            vlines,
        }
            \hline
            \SetCell[c=3]{c}Continuation of Table & & \\
            \hline
            Isoforms & Function in Normal Brain & Function in Pathological Brain\\
        \end{tblr}
    }
    \DefTblrTemplate{capcont}{MyTmp}{%
        \UseTblrTemplate{conthead-text}{MyContTxt}
    }

    % Remove the "Continued on next page" text from footer
    \DefTblrTemplate{firstfoot, middlefoot}{MyFoot}{%
        %
    }
    
    \NewTblrTheme{MyTheme}{
        \SetTblrTemplate{capcont}{MyTmp}%
        \SetTblrTemplate{firstfoot, middlefoot}{MyFoot}%
    }
    
\begin{document}

\begin{longtblr}[
     theme = MyTheme,
     caption = {DUSP genes in normal and pathological brain function},
     label = {long4},
     headsep= -1pt,
     note{} = {\small AD: Alzheimer’s disease; HD: Huntingdon’s disease; CMT4: Charcot-Marie-Tooth Neuropathy Type 4.},
]{
     colspec = {lX[l]X[l]}, 
     width = \textwidth,
     vlines,
}
    \hline
    \SetCell[c=3]{c}DUSP genes in normal and pathological brain function & &\\
    \hline
    Isoforms & Function in Normal Brain & Function in Pathological Brain  \\
    \hline
    SSH1 & long text long text long text long text long text long text  & long textlong text long text long text \\
    SSH2 & long text long text long text long text & long text long text long text long text \\    
    SSH1 & long text long text long text long text long text long text  & long textlong text long text long text long textlong text long text long text \\
    SSH1 & long text long text long text long text long text long text  & long textlong text long text long text \\
    SSH2 & long text long text long text long text & long text long text long text long text \\    
    SSH1 & long text long text long text long text long text long text  & long textlong text long text long text long textlong text long text long text \\
    SSH1 & long text long text long text long text long text long text  & long textlong text long text long text \\
    SSH2 & long text long text long text long text & long text long text long text long text \\    
    SSH1 & long text long text long text long text long text long text  & long textlong text long text long text long textlong text long text long text \\
    SSH1 & long text long text long text long text long text long text  & long textlong text long text long text \\
    SSH2 & long text long text long text long text & long text long text long text long text \\    
    SSH1 & long text long text long text long text long text long text  & long textlong text long text long text long textlong text long text long text \\
    SSH1 & long text long text long text long text long text long text  & long textlong text long text long text \\
    SSH2 & long text long text long text long text & long text long text long text long text \\    
    SSH1 & long text long text long text long text long text long text  & long textlong text long text long text long textlong text long text long text \\
    SSH1 & long text long text long text long text long text long text  & long textlong text long text long text \\
    SSH2 & long text long text long text long text & long text long text long text long text \\    
    SSH1 & long text long text long text long text long text long text  & long textlong text long text long text long textlong text long text long text \\
    SSH1 & long text long text long text long text long text long text  & long textlong text long text long text \\
    SSH2 & long text long text long text long text & long text long text long text long text \\    
    SSH1 & long text long text long text long text long text long text  & long textlong text long text long text long textlong text long text long text \\
    SSH1 & long text long text long text long text long text long text  & long textlong text long text long text \\
    SSH2 & long text long text long text long text & long text long text long text long text \\    
    SSH1 & long text long text long text long text long text long text  & long textlong text long text long text long textlong text long text long text \\
    SSH1 & long text long text long text long text long text long text  & long textlong text long text long text \\
    SSH2 & long text long text long text long text & long text long text long text long text \\    
    SSH1 & long text long text long text long text long text long text  & long textlong text long text long text long textlong text long text long text \\
    SSH1 & long text long text long text long text long text long text  & long textlong text long text long text \\
    SSH2 & long text long text long text long text & long text long text long text long text \\    
    SSH1 & long text long text long text long text long text long text  & long textlong text long text long text long textlong text long text long text \\
    SSH1 & long text long text long text long text long text long text  & long textlong text long text long text \\
    SSH2 & long text long text long text long text & long text long text long text long text \\    
    SSH1 & long text long text long text long text long text long text  & long textlong text long text long text long textlong text long text long text \\
    SSH1 & long text long text long text long text long text long text  & long textlong text long text long text \\
    SSH2 & long text long text long text long text & long text long text long text long text \\    
    SSH1 & long text long text long text long text long text long text  & long textlong text long text long text long textlong text long text long text \\
    SSH1 & long text long text long text long text long text long text  & long textlong text long text long text \\
    SSH2 & long text long text long text long text & long text long text long text long text \\    
    SSH1 & long text long text long text long text long text long text  & long textlong text long text long text long textlong text long text long text \\
    \hline
    \SetCell[c=3]{c} End of Table & &\\
    \hline
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

[image: 1st page]

[image: 2nd page]

[image: 3rd page]

Courtesy: [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/625043/219947) was followed to add a different header in the pages other than the first one.